# How to display custom markers in Map

Tags: leaflet, geojson

Hi I need to display custom markers in map but its unable to display on my map,please help me how to display custom markers.

This is my json Object:

```
{
    "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          [-89.39982622861862, 43.06710857435938 ],
          [-89.39982622861862, 43.06710857435938 ]
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "id": "ci7gsmklj004ahym0qpgca8j7",
      "properties": {
        "icon": {
          "options": {
            "className": "",
            "iconUrl": "/hb/assets/leaflet/images/d.png",
            "iconSize": [ 64, 64],
            "iconAnchor": [ 32, 32],
            "popupAnchor": [  0, -24 ]
          },
          "_initHooksCalled": true
        },
        "text": "Hari",
        "title": "Hunt Area #1"
      },
      "type": "Feature"
    }
     ],
    "type": "FeatureCollection"
    }
```

This is my code:

```
 var layer = new L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/zittelevan.lgjj093b/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={token}', {
                            attribution: 'Attribute data here'
                            maxZoom: 18,
                            token: "Token Here"
                        });
                        var map = new L.map('map', {
                            center:[43.10361493125458,89.52398300170898],
                            zoom: 18,
                            layers: [layer],
                        });

                        L.geoJson(features).addTo(map);
```

I followed different sites but am unable to find a solution properly so that i request you people Please help me how to display custom markers on map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `pointToLayer`(http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-pointtolayer) option of `L.geoJson`. Leafet does not figure out custom marker settings from inspecting the properties hash of GeoJSON features, you need to set it up yourself.Code below.

```
var myIcon = L.icon({
    "className": "",
    "iconUrl": "/hb/assets/leaflet/images/d.png",
    "iconSize": [ 64, 64],
    "iconAnchor": [ 32, 32],
    "popupAnchor": [  0, -24 ]
});
geojsonOptions = {
    pointToLayer: function(feature,latLng) {
        return L.marker(latLng,{icon:myIcon})
    }
}
L.geoJson(features).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did in this way i got the answer

```
var myIcon = L.icon({
"className": "",
"iconUrl": "/hb/assets/leaflet/images/d.png",
"iconSize": [ 64, 64],
"iconAnchor": [ 32, 32],
"popupAnchor": [  0, -24 ]
});

L.marker([44.86475133784528,-88.98447811603546],{icon:myIcon }).addTo(map);
```